# Does it matter where a pipe is reduced when splitting the line?

Tags: plumbing

I want to split a 3/4" cold water line before it enters the water softener.  I want to run a dedicated hard water line to our icemaker, outside faucet and upstairs sink drinking faucet.  My current 3/4" cpvc lines run about 15' after leaving the hot water heater before reducing to 1/2" cpvc lines for the remainder of the house.

My question is,  does it matter when I reduce the 3/4" line after making the Split? Can Ido it immediately with a 3/4" x 3/4" x 1/2" "T" or should the reduction be located further away from the split?

Answer (score 3):

No, it really doesn't matter whether you reduce at or after the split. There's no real benefit from having a length of 3/4" pipe instead of 1/2" if it gets reduced anyway.

If you were talking about an extreme distance with many bends, maybe, or if you had extremely low pressure.

Comment: I agree ice makers don't use much flow and I would change sizes at the T. It is Mich easier to work with smaller diameter tubing than pipe.+

Comment: I would have about 25' of piping with a bend or two; however, none of the items would use much of the hard water.  My dishwasher, washing machine and hot water heater would continue to be supplied by the soft water.